# Ionic + Jasmine + Tslint - Property 'and' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, tslint

everybody. I am building an Ionic app over this [boilerplate](https://github.com/marcoturi/ionic2-boilerplate).
Right now, I am building the tests for a specific page and I am using jasmine to mock the providers and set the expected behavior for the methods.
That's how the **beforeEach()** method looks like looks like:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
          mockLoadingController = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create', 'present', 'dismiss']);
          mockLoadingController.create.and.returnValue(mockLoadingController);

          mockModalController =  jasmine.createSpyObj('LoadingController', ['create', 'present',
            'onDidDismiss', 'dismiss']);
          mockModalController.create.and.returnValue(mockModalController);

          mockGeolocation =  jasmine.createSpyObj('Geolocation', ['getCurrentPosition']);

          mockGeolocation.getCurrentPosition.and.callFake(( ) => {
            return {then: ( ) => { }};
          });
          mockEvents = jasmine.createSpyObj('Events', ['publish', 'subscribe']);
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [
              { provide: NavController, useValue: mockNavController },
              { provide: LoadingController, useValue: mockLoadingController },
              { provide: ModalController, useValue: mockModalController },
              { provide: Geolocation, useValue: mockGeolocation },
              { provide: Events, useValue: mockEvents },
              LocationPage,
            ],
          },
    ); } );
```

The problem starts when I define the promise return for the **getCurrentPosition** method:

```
    mockGeolocation.getCurrentPosition.and.callFake(( ) => {
            return {then: ( ) => { }};
    });
```

I am using tslint while testing and, it gives me the following error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/pages/location/location.page.spec.ts:24:40 
    TS2339: Property 'and' does not exist on type '(options?: GeolocationOptions) => Promise<Geoposition>'.
```

The question is: how can I overcame this matter so TSLint does not complain about this code anymore?

Comment: It seems your problem is not with tslint. Your code `mockGeolocation.getCurrentPosition.and.callFake` is wrong. I think it need to be something like: `mockGeolocation.create.and.getCurrentPosition....`. Take a look at the pattern for the other mocks (e.g. `mockModalController`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually proper types will be:

```
  let mockGeolocation: jasmine.SpyObj<Geolocation>;
  let mockEvents: jasmine.SpyObj<Events>;
```

Comment: Thanks fot the precise details! Indeed it worked like this.

Answer (score 8):

Problem solved!
I forgot to detail the way I was declaring the variables:

```
describe('Location Page', () => {
  let mockLoadingController: any;
  let mockModalController: any;
  let mockGeolocation: Geolocation;
  let mockEvents: Events;
  beforeEach(() => {
  //rest of the code here
```

As you can see, I defined a type to the **mockGeolocation** variable and I did set the others as **any**. Setting all the variables as any works perfectly with jasmine and it does not generate an error in tslint.

So the correct code works like this:

```
describe('Location Page', () => {
  let mockLoadingController: any;
  let mockModalController: any;
  let mockGeolocation: any;
  let mockEvents: any;
  beforeEach(() => {
```

Comment: Oh, Man! Thank you very much!
It was exactly my problem.

Comment: Setting the type to `any` is never the _correct_ solution.  It may be a work-around but it's definitely not correct.  All that is doing is bypassing the type system.